# .htaccess with SilverStripe and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, silverstripe

Ok, basically I need to be able to set my .htaccess so that it works for SilverStripe install in root directory and blogs installed in the /blogs directory.  Here is what I have:

```
### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 403 /silverstripe-cache(/|$)
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    # BEGIN Silverstripe
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    # END Silverstripe

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteBase /blogs/aquiman/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blogs/aquiman/index.php [L]

    RewriteBase /blogs/aquipad/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blogs/aquipad/index.php [L]
    # END WordPress

</IfModule>
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
```

This of course does not work.  And I know it is wrong, but I don't know enough to fix it.  Please help me correct this to make it work right.

Thanks,
JH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple advise `keep it separate` i.e.

- Keep `SilverStripe` related code in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` with `RewriteBase /`
- Keep `Wordpress` related code in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/blog/.htaccess` with `RewriteBase /blog/`

Here is a modified Rewrite code you should use in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess:`

```
# BEGIN Silverstripe
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule (?!^blog/)^.*$ sapphire/main.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# END Silverstripe
```

Comment: Ok, for the most part that works.  For example, all the SilverStripe stuff seems fine.  The permalinked categories and posts are fine.  But accessing of actual php files in the blogs subdirectories apart from the initial index.php does not work (ie ../blogs/aquiman/wp-login.php does not work) and it does not seem to find the CSS page.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I take that back.  I guess the blog was seeing an old cached version.  Nothing works in the blogs subdirectory.

Comment: Ok, the blog is back but no CSS.  However, now Silverstripe shows up with the home page but you get no subpages or able to get to the login for the admin page.

Comment: Made another edit. You man css not showing for WP or Silverstrip? Make sure your css patchs are absolute not relative.

Comment: I will check it in a bit.  FTP went down and I have to wait.

Comment: Ok, I didn't need that last edit.  It must have been a cache issue.  Because when I got to my second job I loaded it up to see if it would work and it all works.  So, THANKS!!!